# Linux - generic network configuration

Tags: linux, networking, configuration

I am creating a set of utilities to configure a Linux system for a particular network and domain configuration. One of the steps of this configuration is configuring the network interface. Although I can easily configure things like Samba, or NTP (since they have the same configuration file syntax, regardless of distro), networking seems to be a bit more difficult.

With Debian using `/etc/network/interfaces`, Fedora and Red Hat using `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, and other distros using their respective network managers (I personally use netctl on Arch), getting a script to be able to configure a network interface seems nearly impossible. Is there any portable way of configuring a network interface?

Failing that, what would be a good way to create 'modules' for various distros? My project will use Autotools for configuring and installing the utilities, so some 'compilation' can be done then, but how can I detect which network manager is in use? Problems with this approach include what to do when no module exists for the network manager in use. Or should I leave it to the compiling user to decide which 'module' to enable?

This question then extends to packaging - when creating this as a package, how can I support the multiple network managers in existence, even on one distro? In Arch, for example, the user may have netctl installed, which uses one set of configuration files, or Wicd or perhaps GNOME network-manager.

Comment: Both wicd and network-manager seems to provide D-Bus interface. So you can check in your software, if one of these daemons was registered under D-Bus.

Comment: Alternatively you can just define NM or Wicd to be a requirement, so the user must use one of these tools to use your software. In this case you have a defined environment, so your software will be not that complicated.

Comment: @yegorich Should I make the decision which 'module' to enable at compile time, or run time though?

Comment: If you mean D-Bus stuff, then at run-time. You can even design your software with some kind of plug-in API. One plug-in for NM, one for Wicd, one for netctl etc. The API describes, how to configure a network interface. The user can then choose, which plug-in to compile, depending on his system configuration.

Comment: @yegorich want to write that up as a formal answer? It seems like the best approach to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your software with plug-in API in mind. The API describes, how network interface can be configured. You would then have one plug-in for NM, one for Wicd, one for /etc/network/interfaces etc. The user can choose, what plug-ins to compile during the `./configure` stage, so that he doesn't need to install unneeded dependencies.

For multiple enabled plug-ins (for example NM and Wicd) you can use D-Bus to check, what service is registered to manage network interfaces.